# calibration_params = bme280.load_calibration_params(bus, address)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

so I'm trying to utilize a BME280 to send data to Initial State however, when using the following code:

```
port = 1
address = 0x76
bus = smbus2.SMBus(port)
calibration_params = bme280.load_calibration_params(bus, address)

streamer = Streamer(bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME, bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY, access_key=ACCESS_KEY)
while True:
        bme280data = bme280.sample(bus, address, calibration_params)
        humidity = format(bme280data.humidity, ".1f")
        temp_c = bme280data.temperature
        if METRIC_UNITS:
                streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + "Temperature(C)", temp_c)
        else:
                temp_f = format(temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0, ".1f")
                streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Temperature(F)", temp_f)
        streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + "Humidity(%)", humidity)
        streamer.flush()
        time.sleep(60*MINUTES_BETWEEN_READS)
```

I'm presented with the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_calibration_params'

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you,

So far I've attempted to fix all indentation errors and warnings as well as making sure that RPI.bme280 is installed and this has brought me no luck thus far. I'm not sure what else I can attempt as I am quite new to python and these types of projects on a whole.

Comment: Is your file called bme280.py. If so, change it.

Comment: I changed it to simply just temperaturesensor.py just in case and still had issues with it!

Comment: Have you tried looking into your bme280 module file.
Also try running `pip3 show RPi.bme280` to check python has it.

Comment: So look for a file called bme280.py in the module files or? And this is something I can try when getting back to the project tomorrow!

Comment: There is a [post](https://github.com/rm-hull/bme280/issues/12) that might help, it seems to explain it better than I could. See if this helps.